# How to select all class that is above certain tag using CSS Selector in Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, css-selectors

Here I want to get all the class = "result-row" which are above the "h4" tag, not the ones which are below "h4" tag.

[image]

My current code selects all of them:

```
section = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='rows']")
result_rows = section.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result-row")
```

so how can i get the desired result here?

Comment: please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html so we can test with it. Also the url if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following css which uses :not to filter out h4's  general siblings based on class

```
li.result-row:not(h4.ban ~ li.result-row)
```

which might be simplified to:

```
.result-row:not(.ban ~ .result-row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If CSS is not obligatory, you can use XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4/previous-sibling::li")
```